# "People reached" doesn't measure people

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, people-reached

Wow! *670k people reached.*

That's incredible!

Literally...not credible.

Indeed, according to the title text, that's 670k **views**, not **people**.

[image]

Possible fixes:

1. Change the statistic to measure people (realizing, of course, that unauthenticated users cannot be reliably disambiguated).
2. Change the label to "views".

I'd love #1, but I imagine that would be quite a bit harder.

---

P.S. Pickiness aside, I really do like the new profile changes.

Comment: [I completely agree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244916/178816).

Comment: It measures views.  From programmers, not people.  You made the same programmer happy at least 5 times.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @HansPassant, right, that's fine. I just suggest that it say that: "views" (not "people")

Comment: Right. When the "people reached" can exceed the number of people in the world, I agree it's a bit silly.

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/users/2576539/patrick-w-mcmahon, who is reported to have reached 2.7m people with 34 answers and 7 questions. How is that possible? I have 1,342 answers, and I have only reached 1.6m people. How could that be?

Comment: Wait, you don't believe that Jon Skeet has reached 246.9m people?

Answer (score 14):

Views, in the sense of SE sites, are **unique** views, which can be roughly translated into people (though it is not a 100% accurate translation). They've said they are okay with this number being higher than it actually might be:

> we'd rather slightly over-appreciate volunteers then under-appreciate
>   'em

This post on MSE shares a lot about the new stat: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

So, you're right, to an extent, but it is the best guestimate that they can come up with with the data they collect.

Comment: Remember, you can help one person 500 times (and it would count that many times).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I meant the same person could view 500 of your posts, not the *same* post obviously :) Since it totals the views of all your helpful posts, they would all count

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: ah...I see. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - yup. I will always appreciate the [How to exit the Vim editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor) question/answer